# I know "This suggested edit to your post has already been handled" -- I handled it!

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I rejected [this edit suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/758189) on one of my own posts. But when I view it, it tells me:

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.

Although that's true--it was handled (by me) and my action is no longer required (because I already took action)--it confused me into thinking perhaps another user had handled the edit after all. It seems to me that this wording doesn't really make sense when *I* was the one who handled the edit.

**Is it the intended behavior of the system to show that message, even for edits that I myself rejected (or accepted)? Or is this considered a bug?**

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I just pushed the change to clarify the message when the post author is looking at the edit in review after either voting in the first place or overriding the review result.

Comment: @AdamLear *"You have already voted on this suggested edit to your post and no further action is required."* Great--thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer, but I just like to add more info to this issue.

I was searching for when this message shows up in case this was some generic message that shows under any circumstances. Here's what I found out (the conditions may be different for mods/10k+):

- This doesn't show on reviews of posts that aren't mine. Whether I was one of the reviewers or not, doesn't seem to matter.
- That exact message shows under 2 conditions (In both cases, I have to be the owner of the post):

  1. By itself; when I had reviewed an edit on own post (Ex: Like the on the Question).
  2. Accompanied by another message; when I have not participated in the edit review of my own post *and* that suggested edit is the last one on my post *and* the suggested edit has been approved. For example, I could see it on this [suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/110774).

     > This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.
     >
     > If you disagree with this edit being approved, you can return your post to its previous state using the Reject button below.

[image: Suggested edit review]

Once I edited that post myself (I removed an irrelevant tag), the second line disappeared and I can see the first line only as that suggested edit was no longer the last edit.

So it looks like it is some kind of Generic message, which is accompanied by other messages depending on available actions that we may do after the review is completed. But I don't know if there's any other case than the one shared in the screenshots above.

Comment: This may actually answer my question, in that the added "If you disagree..." text when the edit suggestion was already handled by other users suggests the existing behavior is intended. It would be nicer if it said, "You have already handled this suggested edit to your post"--depending on what else people come up with here, perhaps I'll eventually post a [meta-tag:feature-request] for that on [meta.se].

Comment: @EliahKagan This is an oversight on my part. :) The original change is documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296166/user-experience-of-overriding-communitys-decision-on-suggested-edit/298526#298526) and I even got a ping about the very issue you describe... which I promptly got distracted from. I'll fix it up this week.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for your attention to this! But is this really the same bug was reported [in that comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296166/user-experience-of-overriding-communitys-decision-on-suggested-edit/298526#comment973150_298526)? There, a user created a new tag wiki, then edited the tag wiki, and the edit went through review because the user had less than 20k reputation. In my case, however, I made the post but *didn't* make the subsequent edit. Instead I rejected an edit someone else had suggested. Does the forthcoming fix apply to both these situations?

Comment: @EliahKagan Assuming I do it right... yes. :)

Comment: @AdamLear Excellent--thanks! Since I'm guessing this meta question might just get a [meta-tag:status-completed] and no additional answer after your fix is rolled out, I'm accepting this answer (which describes the current behavior).